# Cannot access mysql procedures body

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to edit my MySql stored procedures at Hostgator but all i get is empty body in Navicat, in PhpMyAdmin the edit button is just not clickable.
I suspect it has something to do with the definer field which states: "***_SA@31.210.186.*" my IP is not static but for some reason the definer has IP in it, how can i fix this problem?

Comment: can you drop it, and run a block without definer ?

Comment: by drop you mean delete?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-procedure.html

Comment: dropped one from PhpMyAdmin, but i need the contents of the stored procedures, so i won't need to rewrite, isn't there something i can do?

Comment: when I used hostgator, i contacted them and they gave me ssh access. so then inside mysql command line .... `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE myStoredProcName`

Comment: and, as you probably created sp's anyway, you already have it in a script, no ?

Comment: no, used navicat to write them :/

Comment: so you write and test stored procs on the fly ? without saving them in scripts I guess you are saying?

Comment: well i am developing it from scratch so yes, i just create them on fly

Comment: just save the ones you care about to a .sql file :>

Comment: i would,but i can't access the procedures anymore, only invoke

Comment: well, gain ssh access like i said, read above. Hostgator allows it